# Solving an (easy?) inequality involving the norm-1

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

Let $b:\mathbb{N_0}\to \mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}$ be an increasing function such that $b(0)=0$, and fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Some computations have led me to being in need of proving the following inequality for all but finite $x\in \mathbb{N}_0^n$ :

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:1}
C\ \sum_{i=1}^nb(x_i) - \sum_{i=1}^nb(x_i)\ x_i \leqslant 0  \tag{1} 
\end{equation}
or at least this weaker inequality ( for some $ D>0 )$
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:2}
C\ \sum_{i=1}^nb(x_i) - \sum_{i=1}^nb(x_i)\ x_i \leqslant D  \tag{2} 
\end{equation}
where $C>0$ is a fixed constant. As it may be clear, with a slight abuse of notation, we could express \eqref{eqn:1} in terms of the norm-1 like this:

$$  C\ || B(x)||_1 - ||B(x)*x||_1 \leqslant 0 $$

Where "$ * $" would be a multiplication coordinate by coordinate between vectors and $B(x):=(b(x_1),...,b(x_n)) $.

Also It may be helpful to see inequality \eqref{eqn:1} in this fashion:
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:3}
\sum_{i=1}^nb(x_i)(C-x_i) \leqslant 0  \tag{3} 
\end{equation}

So far, my intuition tells me that "sufficiently away from $\overrightarrow{0}$" (say, in the complement of $\mathcal{C}_K:=\{ ||x||_1\leqslant K\}$, for big $K$) this must hold.
I have some ideas but nothing clear enough to write down here yet.

Any suggestions are welcome!

EDIT 1:

If b is bounded, then its easy to show that \eqref{eqn:1} holds outside some $\mathcal{C}_K$.

EDIT 2:

I think I've come up with a proof. I haven't posted it as an answer because it doesn't seem to depend on the function $b$, and so maybe I'm making some silly mistake. I'd be grateful if anyone could point it out to me in that case.

We begin by the following simple and useful observation: If, for some $K$ and some $x\in \mathbb{N}_0^n$  $||x||_1 > K$, then there is some $i\in\mathbb{N}_0$ such that $x_i>K/n$.

Now, given $x\in \mathbb{N_0}$, lets define 
$$J_x^+:=\{j\in\{1,...,n\}: C-x_j\geqslant 0\}\ \ \ \ J_x^-:=\{j\in\{1,...,n\}: C-x_j < 0\}$$

For our purposes, we need to assume that $J_x^-\neq \emptyset $. By the observation, it's sufficient to assume

\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:4}
||x||_1>K:=C.n \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Now lets see that \eqref{eqn:4} is sufficient for \eqref{eqn:1} to hold. We have:

$$ \sum_{j=1}^nb(x_j)(C-x_j) = \sum\limits_{j\in J^+_x}b(x_j)(C-x_j) + \sum\limits_{j\in J^-_x}b(x_j)(C-x_j) $$

Now, given that $b$ is an increasing function and given the definition of $J_x^+,\ J_x^-$, we have that, for each term of each sum, 
$$ b(x_j)(C-x_j)\leqslant b(C) (C-x_j)$$

So

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^nb(x_j)(C-x_j) <b(C) ( \sum\limits_{j\in J^+_x}(C-x_j) + \sum\limits_{j\in J^-_x}(C-x_j)) = b(C) (C.n-||x||_1)
\end{equation}

And the last expression is less than zero iff equation \eqref{eqn:4} holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We begin by the following simple and useful observation: If, for some $K$ and some $x∈\mathbb{N}^n_0$ we have $||x||_1>K$ , then there is some $i∈\mathbb{N}_0$ such that $x_i>K/n$.

Now, given $x∈\mathbb{N}^n_0$, lets define
$$J^+_x:=\{j∈\{1,...,n\}:C−x_j⩾0\}\ \ \ \ J^−_x:=\{j∈\{1,...,n\}:C−x_j<0\}$$

For our purposes, we need to assume that $J^−_x≠∅$. By the observation, it's sufficient to assume

\begin{equation}
||x||_1>K:=C.n \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Now lets see that $(4)$ is sufficient for the inequality $(1)$ to hold. We have:

$$∑\limits_{j=1}^nb(x_j)(C−x_j)=∑\limits_{j∈J^+_x}b(x_j)(C−x_j)+∑\limits_{j∈J^-_x}b(x_j)(C−x_j)$$

Now, given that $b$ is an increasing function and given the definition of $J^+_x$ and $J^−_x$, we have that, for each term of each sum,

$$ b(x_j)(C−x_j)⩽b(C)(C−x_j) $$

So

$$ ∑\limits_{j=1}^nb(x_j)(C−x_j)< b(C)(∑\limits_{j∈J^+_x}(C−x_j)+∑\limits_{j∈J^-_x}(C−x_j))=b(C)(C.n−||x||_1) $$

And the last expression is less than zero iff equation \eqref{eqn:4} holds.